# Vitali Hahn Saks Theorem application

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal M,\mu)$ be a measure space such that $ \mu(X)<\infty$. Suppose that $(f_n)$ is a sequence in $L^p(X)$ such that $|f_k|$ converges weakly to $|f|$ in $L^p(X)$. A solution to a problem I found in a book (*Problems and Solutions in Mathematics - Major American Universities PHD Qualifying Questions and Solutions*)  says that it follows by the Vitali-Hahn-Saks for any $ \varepsilon >0$ there exists $ \delta>0$ such that $$   \int_E |f_k| d\mu + \int_E |f| d \mu < \varepsilon$$
whenever $\mu(E)<\delta$.

My question is:

> What is the Vitali Hahn Saks Theorem (I remember seeing it, but I forgot where, and Google didn't help much) and how does the theorem apply here.

Comment: I don't understand why they use this theorem. Since $|f_k|$ converge weakly to $|f|$ and $\mathbf 1_X$ is integrable, we have for a fixed $\varepsilon$ an integer $n_0$ such that if $k\geq n_0$ then $\int_X |f_k|d\mu\leq\int_X |f|d\mu +\frac{\varepsilon}2$. We can find a $\delta>0$ such that $\int_E |f|d\mu\leq \frac{\varepsilon}2$ if $\mu(E)\leq \delta$ (first approximate $|f|$ by a simple function), so we have $\int_E(|f_k|+|f|)d\mu\leq \varepsilon$ for $k\geq n_0$. Apply what we did for $|f|$ to $|f_k|$ for $k<n_0$ to get the wanted inequality.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo: I figured there is an easier way, but I was curious how that theorem applies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of Vitali-Hahn-Saks they are using is found e.g. in Yosida, "Functional Analysis", sec. II.2.  The measures $|f_k| \ d\mu$ and $|f| \ d\mu$ are absolutely continuous wrt $\mu$, and the theorem asserts that this absolute continuity is uniform in $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer.